# pandas/dask csv multiple line read

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dask

I have CSV this way:

```
name,sku,description
Bryce Jones,lay-raise-best-end,"Art community floor adult your single type. Per back community former stock thing."
John Robinson,cup-return-guess,Produce successful hot tree past action young song. Himself then tax eye little last state vote. Country down list that speech economy leave.
Theresa Taylor,step-onto,"**Choice should lead budget task. Author best mention.
Often stuff professional today allow after door instead. Model seat fear evidence. Now sing opportunity feeling no season show.**"
```

that whole multi-line is value of description column of 3rd row

But when

```
df = ddf.read_csv(
    file_path,blocksize=2000,engine="python",encoding='utf-8-sig',quotechar='"',delimiter='[,]',quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL
)
```

I use the above code it reads this way

```
['Bryce Jones', 'lay-raise-best-end', '"Art community floor adult your single type. Per back community former stock thing."']
['John Robinson', 'cup-return-guess', 'Produce successful hot tree past action young song. Himself then tax eye little last state vote. Country down list that speech economy leave.']
['Theresa Taylor', 'step-onto', '"Choice should lead budget task. Author best mention.']
['Often stuff professional today allow after door instead. Model seat fear evidence. Now sing opportunity feeling no season show."', None, None]
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

## 1

You can use double linebreak between rows and single linebreak inside texts and `pandas` will understand. So, `csv` will be-

```
name,sku,description

Bryce Jones,lay-raise-best-end,"Art community floor adult your single type. Per back community former stock thing."

John Robinson,cup-return-guess,Produce successful hot tree past action young song. Himself then tax eye little last state vote. Country down list that speech economy leave.

Theresa Taylor,step-onto,"Choice should lead budget task. Author best mention.
Often stuff professional today allow after door instead. Model seat fear evidence. Now sing opportunity feeling no season show."
```

And here is how you read it.

```
df = pd.read_csv(filepath) # you can keep other parameters if you want
```

output is,

```
             name                 sku  \
0     Bryce Jones  lay-raise-best-end   
1   John Robinson    cup-return-guess   
2  Theresa Taylor           step-onto   

                                         description  
0  Art community floor adult your single type. Pe...  
1  Produce successful hot tree past action young ...  
2  Choice should lead budget task. Author best me...
```

## 2

Use `\n` where you need linebreaks.

```
name,sku,description
Bryce Jones,lay-raise-best-end,"Art community floor adult your single type. Per back community former stock thing."
John Robinson,cup-return-guess,Produce successful hot tree past action young song. Himself then tax eye little last state vote. Country down list that speech economy leave.
Theresa Taylor,step-onto,"Choice should lead budget task. Author best mention.\nOften stuff professional today allow after door instead. Model seat fear evidence. Now sing opportunity feeling no season show."
```

While reading, use `codecs` library of python.

```
import codecs
df = pd.read_csv('../../data/stack.csv')
print(codecs.decode(df.iloc[2,2], 'unicode_escape'))
```

Output:

```
Choice should lead budget task. Author best mention.
Often stuff professional today allow after door instead. Model seat fear evidence. Now sing opportunity feeling no season show.
```

We had to use `codecs.decode()` because `pandas` escapes the character `\` with `\\`. And decoding undo that. Without `print()` function, you will not see the linebreak though.

Comment: the description column is multiline and that is the reason I am getting issues in parsing. you have formatted it to single so it worked easily